# Multithreading - web-scraping - Python

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape this Italian website : https://www.natitrentino.mondotrentino.net/ that contains genealogical information. My code works good but there are 1 300 000 pages. I would like to add a multithread to scrape data faster. Can someone please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code without multithreading:

```html
import requests
import tabula
import pandas as pd

    
first_page = 16999
last_page = 17500

def url_ok(url):
    r = requests.head(url)
    return r.status_code == 200

general = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Cognome','Nome', 'Nome del padre', 'Cognome della madre', 'Nome della madre', 'Data di nascita', 'Parrocchia', 'Comune', 'URL'])
for i in range(first_page, last_page):
    pdf_path = f'https://www.natitrentino.mondotrentino.net/natiintrentino/viewprint/{i}'
    if url_ok(f'https://www.natitrentino.mondotrentino.net/natiintrentino/viewprint/{i}') == False:
        i = i+1
    else:
        y1 = 89.45
        x1 = 25.8
        y2 = y1 + 193.199
        x2 = x1 + 447
        dfs = tabula.read_pdf(pdf_path, stream=True, pages=1, area=(y1,x1,y2,x2), guess=False)
        intermediate = dfs[0].set_index("Cognome").T
        intermediate['URL'] = f'https://www.natitrentino.mondotrentino.net/natiintrentino/viewprint/{i}'
        general = general.append(intermediate)
        print(general)
    print(i)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

below can be a solution.

the main idea is to distribute the numbers of pages 17500 - 16999 amongst the threads .

which is done by

```
offsets = [(last_page-first_page) // number_of_threads + (1 if x < (last_page -
                                                                    first_page) % number_of_threads else 0) for x in range(number_of_threads)]
```

each offset is then added to start_page to move forward and this load is given to each thread

```
 import requests
import tabula
import pandas as pd
import math
import threading

first_page = 16999
last_page = 17500

number_of_threads = 4

# # divide last_page-firstpage into equal parts 
# if the number of threads = 4 then the below will divide 17500-16999 into equal Parts 
# [126, 125, 125, 125]
# can adjust the number of threads to increase the threads 
offsets = [(last_page-first_page) // number_of_threads + (1 if x < (last_page -
                                                                    first_page) % number_of_threads else 0) for x in range(number_of_threads)]

def scrape(start, end):
    print(f'starting to scrape from {start} to {end}')
    for i in range(start, end):
        pdf_path = f'https://www.natitrentino.mondotrentino.net/natiintrentino/viewprint/{i}'
        if url_ok(f'https://www.natitrentino.mondotrentino.net/natiintrentino/viewprint/{i}') == False:
            i = i+1
        else:
            y1 = 89.45
            x1 = 25.8
            y2 = y1 + 193.199
            x2 = x1 + 447
            dfs = tabula.read_pdf(pdf_path, stream=True,
                                  pages=1, area=(y1, x1, y2, x2), guess=False)
            intermediate = dfs[0].set_index("Cognome").T
            intermediate[
                'URL'] = f'https://www.natitrentino.mondotrentino.net/natiintrentino/viewprint/{i}'
            general = general.append(intermediate)
            print(general)
        print(i)


def url_ok(url):
    r = requests.head(url)
    return r.status_code == 200


for offset in offsets:
    start = first_page
    first_page += offset
    threading.Thread(name="child", target=scrape, args=(start, first_page)).start()
```

Note: there might be some overlaps in the offsets